How do I handle 500 and 200 error on phalcon?
I was wondering, what's the best way to handle 500 and 200 error in Phalcon? I'd like to create a default error page for when an error occurs.
In my app/config/service.php:
use \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher as PhDispatcher;

$di->set(
'dispatcher',
function() use ($di) {

    $evManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');

    $evManager->attach(
        "dispatch:beforeException",
        function($event, $dispatcher, $exception)
        {
            switch ($exception->getCode()) {
                case PhDispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
                case PhDispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:

                    $dispatcher->forward(
                        array(
                            'namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Web',
                            'controller' => 'error',
                            'action'     => 'show404',
                        )
                    );
                    return false;
            }
        }
    );
    $dispatcher = new PhDispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($evManager);
    return $dispatcher;
},
true
);

Thank you!

HTTP 200 is no error...
